# Connection must be valid and open C3

Tags: c#, php, mysql

Im getting this problem when trying to run my .exe c# pdf form filling. The software should get 2 ID variables from a php page and then fill the pdf forms with data from local database (xampp localhost). When the page is trying to execute the program it just crashes with this error. Any ideea where i might get it wrong here ? (newbie programmer).

EDIT : i think i managed to fix the valid and open connection problem but now i get conection is already open : (

EDIT 2 : nope, same error.

EDIT 3 : Finally i managed to get the connection working. however i get System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array. error whenever i try to run the program. i think the arrays are empty for some reason.i guessed that the php script wont send the id's i need for the SELECT query and set the id's manualy to 1 (int idagent = 1) but still no luck. any ideea why ? Another question its there a way to check if my php script its sending the ID's i need for this script ? Thanks :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using iTextSharp;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.xml;
using System.IO;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;




namespace PdfGenerator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FillForm();
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// List all of the form fields into a textbox.  The
        /// form fields identified can be used to map each of the
        /// fields in a PDF.
        /// </summary>
        private void ListFieldNames()
        {
            string pdfTemplate = @"C:\xampp\htdocs\site\pdfgen\PdfGenerator\form.pdf";

            // title the form
            this.Text += " - " + pdfTemplate;

            // create a new PDF reader based on the PDF template document
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);

            // create and populate a string builder with each of the 
            // field names available in the subject PDF
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (DictionaryEntry de in pdfReader.AcroFields.Fields)
            {
                sb.Append(de.Key.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
            }

            // Write the string builder's content to the form's textbox
            textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
            textBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
        }

        public static int Param1 { get; set; }
        public static int Param2 { get; set; }

        private void FillForm()
        {

            int idfirma = Param1;
            int idagent = Param2;






            using (var connection = new MySqlConnection("server = localhost; User Id = root; password = ; database = documente;"))
            {
                string agenti = "SELECT * FROM `agenti` WHERE `ID` = @id";
                connection.Open();
                using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(agenti, connection))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", idagent);
                    using (MySqlDataReader result = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
                    {
                        var myArray = new string[,] { };
                        var counter = 0;
                        while (result.Read())
                        {
                            myArray[counter, 0] = (string)result["Nume Agent"];
                            myArray[counter, 1] = (string)result["Telefon"];
                            myArray[counter, 2] = (string)result["Sigiliu"];
                            myArray[counter, 3] = (string)result["Legitimatie"];
                            myArray[counter, 4] = (string)result["Prefix"];
                            counter++;

                        }
                        result.Close();


                        string datef = "SELECT * FROM `dateclienti` WHERE `ID` = @id";
                        using (var cmds = new MySqlCommand(datef, connection))
                        {
                            cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", idfirma);
                            connection.Open();

                            using (MySqlDataReader result2 = cmds.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
                            {
                                var counter2 = 0;
                                var myArray2 = new string[,] { };
                                while (result2.Read())
                                {
                                    myArray2[counter2, 0] = (string)result2["Nume Societate"];
                                    myArray2[counter2, 1] = (string)result2["Adresa Sediu"];
                                    myArray2[counter2, 2] = (string)result2["Adresa Punct de lucru 1"];
                                    myArray2[counter2, 3] = (string)result2["Adresa Punct de lucru 2"];
                                    myArray2[counter2, 4] = (string)result2["Registul Comertului"];
                                    myArray2[counter2, 5] = (string)result2["Cod Fiscal"];
                                    myArray2[counter2, 6] = (string)result2["E-Mail"];
                                    myArray2[counter2, 7] = (string)result2["Cont Banca"];
                                    myArray2[counter2, 8] = (string)result2["Tip casa de marcat"];
                                    myArray2[counter2, 9] = (string)result2["Model casa de marcat"];
                                    myArray2[counter2, 10] = (string)result2["Data de achizitie"];
                                    myArray2[counter2, 11] = (string)result2["Configuratie"];
                                    myArray2[counter2, 12] = (string)result2["Serie casa"];
                                    myArray2[counter2, 13] = (string)result2["Serie fiscala"];
                                    myArray2[counter2, 14] = (string)result2["Nume Pers. De contact"];
                                    myArray2[counter2, 15] = (string)result2["Functie"];
                                    myArray2[counter2, 16] = (string)result2["Serie CI"];
                                    myArray2[counter2, 17] = (string)result2["CNP"];
                                    myArray2[counter2, 18] = (string)result2["Eliberat de"];
                                    myArray2[counter2, 19] = (string)result2["La data de"];
                                    myArray2[counter2, 20] = (string)result2["Telefon"];
                                    myArray2[counter2, 21] = (string)result2["Data"];
                                    counter2++;

                                }
                                result2.Close();













                                string pdfTemplate = @"C:\xampp\htdocs\site\pdfgen\PdfGenerator\form.pdf";
                                string newFile = @"C:\xampp\htdocs\site\pdfgen\PdfGenerator\completed_form.pdf";

                                PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
                                PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(
                                            newFile, FileMode.Create));

                                AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;

                                // set form pdfFormFields

                                // The first worksheet and W-4 form
                                pdfFormFields.SetField("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].regcomert[0]", myArray[4,4]);
                                pdfFormFields.SetField("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].adresafirmabenef[0]", "@adresasediu");
                                pdfFormFields.SetField("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].dataa[0]", "@data");
                                pdfFormFields.SetField("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].numeagent[0]", "@numeagent");
                                pdfFormFields.SetField("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].codfiscal[0]", "@ro");
                                pdfFormFields.SetField("topmostSubform[0].Page2[0].numefirmabenef[0]", "@numefirmabenef");
                                pdfFormFields.SetField("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].fuctie[0]", "@functie");
                                pdfFormFields.SetField("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].reprezentatfirma[0]", "@repfirma");
                                pdfFormFields.SetField("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].tipcasademarc[0]", "@tipcasa");
                                pdfFormFields.SetField("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].dataa[1]", "@data");
                                pdfFormFields.SetField("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].numefirmabenef[0]", "@numefirmabenef");
                                pdfFormFields.SetField("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].nrtelrepfirma[0]", "@nrtelfirma");
                                pdfFormFields.SetField("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].modelcasamarc[0]", "@modelcasa");
                                pdfFormFields.SetField("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].nrpv[0]", "SRN1001");
                                pdfFormFields.SetField("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].telefonagent[0]]", "@telefonagent");



                                // flatten the form to remove editting options, set it to false
                                // to leave the form open to subsequent manual edits
                                pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;

                                // close the pdf
                                pdfStamper.Close();

                            }


                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed the itext and pdf tags, because your issue appears not to be in that part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually open the connection at some point. The command will not do this for you:

```
using (var connection = new MySqlConnection("server = localhost; User Id = root; password = ; database = documente;"))
{
    connection.Open(); // open connection before using it
    string agenti = "SELECT * FROM `agenti` WHERE `ID` = @id";
    using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(agenti, connection))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", idagent);
        using (MySqlDataReader result = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
        {
            var myArray = new string[] { };
            while (result.Read())
            {
                myArray[0] = (string)result["Nume Agent"];
                myArray[1] = (string)result["Telefon"];
                myArray[2] = (string)result["Sigiliu"];
                myArray[3] = (string)result["Legitimatie"];
                myArray[4] = (string)result["Prefix"];

            }
            result.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

You will also then run into issues in the second query. Because you have set `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection` in the first query, you will need to open the connection again before executing the second one.

Comment: Thanks, but i managed to fix that problem. Now im getting another problem. Il edit the post a bit.